# frames using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frame, frames

What's wrong with my codes?

frame 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Clicks = 0 ;
function AddClick(){
Clicks = Clicks + 1;
document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML =  Clicks ;
}
localStorage.setItem('Clicks');
</script>
</head>
Fish and Chips
<p align="right"> <input Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Order" onclick=" AddClick()"></p>
```

frame 2

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var loc = "";

function go() {
window.location.href = loc;
}
function set_loc(theURL) {
loc = theURL;
}
window.onload = function() {
            div = document.getElementById("CountedClicks");
            div.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem('variable');
        }
</script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="background-color:#8A4117;height:30%;width:98%;borde-radius:15px" >
You have ordered <span id="CountedClicks">0 </span> items.<br>
<p align="right"><input type=submit name="Submit" value="Checkout" onchange="set_loc('pay.html');" /></a></p>
</div>
```

I can't count the number of clicked buttons from another frame using this.
*NOT MY OWN CODE

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use the "AddClick" function?

Comment: It's totaly wrong written. Post all the code (even with the HTML part)

Answer (score 2):

You never write any data to local storage. You can't getItems that do not exist.

Comment: I used this

    localStorage.setItem('Clicks');

But nothing happened. Is there still something wrong?

Comment: `setItem` takes **two** arguments and the string `'Clicks'` is not the same as the string `'variable'`

Comment: I already changed variable to Clicks but the AddClick function still doesn't work. Although the value of the CountedClicks changed from 0 to 1 but not incrementing.